# How to specific hide key and value from array of object?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display just `value` string to the screen but its currently coming as key and value pairs `"id":0 , "value":"lorem ipsum` . How can i just display `lorem ipsum` using below approach ?

main.html

```
 <li ng-repeat="message in event | limitTo:1000" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span><strong>Log:</strong></span><span>{{message}}</span></li>
```

data

```
Log:{"id":0,"value":"Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of"}
```

ctrl.js

```
safelyAdd({
                id:$scope.event.length,
                value: data
            });

 function safelyAdd(element){
      if(totalRecieved > Bufferlimit){
         $scope.event =[];
         totalRecieved = 0;
    }
      $scope.event.push(element); //then push new item..
      console.log('array',$scope.event);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.` operator and display the value property of message `message.value`

```
 <li ng-repeat="message in event | limitTo:1000" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span><strong>Log:</strong></span><span>{{message.value}}</span></li>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You just used message.value don't used full object mesage

Comment: what is different from the answer i gave?